# Aligning right parenthesis vertically in a multiple-choice test

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I am making a test. Some of the problems have choices, and the choices are mathematical expressions. I have included the code for the first two problems; 1.) has six choices, and 2.) has eight choices.  The choices are labeled as "i.)", "ii.)", ... "viii.)".  I want the first right parenthesis in each row to be aligned vertically.  So, I want the ")" in "i.)" and "iv.)" from 1.) to be aligned with the ")" in "i.)" and "v.)" from 2.).

The code that I provide does have the ")" aligned vertically within each problem. Now I would like to add one extra feature -  the first ")" in all the rows to be the same distance from the left margin.  (I guess that a distance of "4em" would be appropriate.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


    \begin{document}

    \noindent {\bf 1.)} Which of the following functions is graphed?
    \begin{alignat*}{6}
    {\mathrm{i.})} \ &y = (x + 5)^{2}
    \qquad \quad
    &{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &y = \sqrt{x + 5}
    \qquad \quad
    &{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &x = y^{2} + 5
    \\
    {\mathrm{iv.})} \ &y = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} - 25}}{\sqrt{x - 5}}
    \qquad \quad
    &{\mathrm{v.})} \ &y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 5}}
    \qquad \quad
    &{\mathrm{vi.})} \ &\vert x \vert = y^{2} + 5
    \end{alignat*}
    \vskip0.25in
    \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=26,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-3:6.5,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-5,5}
]
\addplot[domain=5:26,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};
\addplot[domain=-6:5,dashed,thin,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};

\draw [densely dashed] (5,3.16227766) -- (5,0);
\draw [fill=white] (5,3.16227766) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent {\bf 2.)} Which of the following products is equal to an integral power of 10?
\begin{alignat*}{8}
{\mathrm{i.})} \ &1
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{ii.})} \ &5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iii.})} \ &5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{80}\right)
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{iv.})} \ &5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{800}\right) \\
{\mathrm{v.})} \ &\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{3}15^{6}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vi.})} \ &2^{-6}25^{-3}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{vii.})} \ &\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)^{3}
\qquad \quad
&{\mathrm{viii.})} \ &\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{5^{4}49}\right)^{3}
\end{alignat*}
\vskip0.25in


\end{document}
```

Comment: If this is for an exam, there are packages that allow you create answers with option easily.

Comment: Or `enumitem` for control over enumerations if you just want something simple. Don't use commands such as `\bf`, though, they are deprecated (from LaTeX 2.09!). Use e.g. `\bfseries` (or `\textbf{}`) instead.

Comment: \makebox[3em][r]{viii)} is a simple replacement.

Comment: @John Kormylo  Since the choices may involve fractions and rational functions, commands involving `makebox` have to be in an align environment.  How do I use your command in an align environment so that the ")" in "i.)" and "iv.)" are 3em from the left margin?

Comment: @cfr  I want to enumerate in a particular way. Can you give me a link for `enumitem`?

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem

Comment: You don't need to alignat so long as you make the boxes all the same width.  $\displaystyle ...$ will do.

Comment: Are you saying that the display of the six or eight choices can be typeset using the tabbing environment, with the mathematical expressions in the choices typeset using the `displaystyle` command in math mode?

Answer (score 1):

This is easy with the `tablists` package and also the syntax is much friendler.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepackage{tablists,enumitem,amsmath}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}


\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\bfseries\arabic*.,leftmargin=*]
\item Which of the following functions is graphed?

  \medskip

  \begin{tabenum}[i.)]
  \tabenumitem $y = (x + 5)^{2}$
  \tabenumitem $y = \sqrt{x + 5}$
  \tabenumitem $x = y^{2} + 5$
  \\[1ex]
  \tabenumitem $y = \dfrac{\sqrt{x^{2} - 25}}{\sqrt{x - 5}}$
  \tabenumitem $y = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x + 5}}$
  \tabenumitem $\lvert x \rvert = y^{2} + 5$
  \end{tabenum}

  \begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=26,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-3:6.5,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-5,5}
  ]
  \addplot[domain=5:26,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};
  \addplot[domain=-6:5,dashed,thin,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};

  \draw [densely dashed] (5,3.16227766) -- (5,0);
  \draw [fill=white] (5,3.16227766) circle [radius=1.5pt];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}

\item Which of the following products is equal to an integral power of $10$?

  \medskip

  \begin{tabenum}[i.)]
  \tabenumitem $1$
  \tabenumitem $5^{-3}\left(\dfrac{1}{8}\right)$
  \tabenumitem $5^{-3}\left(\dfrac{1}{80}\right)$
  \tabenumitem $5^{-3}\left(\dfrac{1}{800}\right)$ 
  \\[1ex]
  \tabenumitem $\left(\dfrac{4}{9}\right)^{3}15^{6}$
  \tabenumitem $2^{-6}25^{-3}$
  \tabenumitem $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{6}\left(\dfrac{1}{25}\right)^{3}$
  \tabenumitem $\left(\dfrac{7}{4}\right)^{6}\left(\dfrac{1}{5^{4}49}\right)^{3}$
  \end{tabenum}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I adopted a `tabstack` approach to solving the problem.  Changes to your MWE included:

1) Replacing

```
\begin{alignat*}{8}...\end{alignat*}
```

with

```
\[ \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\kern4em\alignShortstack{...}}\]
```

It has the effect of indenting the aligned Shortstack 4em from the left margin;

2) Replacing all your `\ &` with `&\`; and

3) Using an `\llap` on the first roman-numeral label on each row.  Since the width of the "i) iv)" labels is wider than the width of the "i) v)" labels, and the OP wanted the right parens to align in the first column at 4em, I had to make the labels of column 1 all of zero width, which I did with an `\llap`.

Other parameter definitions employed in the preamble as follows:

- `\stackMath` will make the `\alignShortstack` arguments to be processed in math mode;
- `\setstackgap{S}{10pt}` sets the gap between answer rows to be 10pt;
- `\setstackaligngap{3em}` changes the default horizontal spacing between columns (and was thus used to eliminate all your `quads` and `\qquads`); and
- `\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\displaystyle#1}` is an undocumented way to force all TABstack arguments to be processed in `\displaystyle`.

Here is the revised MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\setstackaligngap{3em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\displaystyle#1}%
\makeatother

    \begin{document}

    \noindent {\bf 1.)} Which of the following functions is graphed?
\[ \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\kern4em\alignShortstack{
    \llap{i.)} &\ y = (x + 5)^{2}
    &{\mathrm{ii.})} &\ y = \sqrt{x + 5}
    &{\mathrm{iii.})} &\ x = y^{2} + 5
    \\
    \llap{iv.)} &\ y = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} - 25}}{\sqrt{x - 5}}
    &{\mathrm{v.})} &\ y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 5}}
    &{\mathrm{vi.})} &\ \vert x \vert = y^{2} + 5
}}\]
    \vskip0.25in
    \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=26,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-3:6.5,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-5,5}
]
\addplot[domain=5:26,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};
\addplot[domain=-6:5,dashed,thin,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};

\draw [densely dashed] (5,3.16227766) -- (5,0);
\draw [fill=white] (5,3.16227766) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent {\bf 2.)} Which of the following products is equal to an integral power of 10?
\[ \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\kern4em\alignShortstack{
\llap{i.)} &\ 1
&{\mathrm{ii.})} &\ 5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)
&{\mathrm{iii.})} &\ 5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{80}\right)
&{\mathrm{iv.})} &\ 5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{800}\right) \\
\llap{v.)} &\ \left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{3}15^{6}
&{\mathrm{vi.})} &\ 2^{-6}25^{-3}
&{\mathrm{vii.})} &\ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)^{3}
&{\mathrm{viii.})} &\ \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{5^{4}49}\right)^{3}
}}\]
\vskip0.25in
\end{document}
```

In the image below, a red line has been added at 4em indent to show the alignment of column 1 right parens across different problems, which was the OP's request.

[image]

---

ADDENDUM:

The following essentially does the same as above, but simplifies the input for adding the answer labels, with the `\LBL{integer}` macro.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textwidth}{6.1in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.0in} \setlength{\textheight}{9in}

\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\setstackaligngap{5em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TAB@delim[1]{\displaystyle#1}%
\makeatother
\newcommand\LBL[1]{\llap{\romannumeral#1.)}}
\begin{document}
\noindent {\bfseries 1.)} Which of the following functions is graphed?
\[ \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\kern4em\alignShortstack{
     \LBL{1} &\ y = (x + 5)^{2}
    &\LBL{2} &\ y = \sqrt{x + 5}
    &\LBL{3} &\ x = y^{2} + 5
    \\
     \LBL{4} &\ y = \frac{\sqrt{x^{2} - 25}}{\sqrt{x - 5}}
    &\LBL{5} &\ y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x + 5}}
    &\LBL{6} &\ \vert x \vert = y^{2} + 5
}}\]
    \vskip0.25in
    \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis equal image,
          xmax=26,ymax=7,
          axis lines=middle,
          restrict y to domain=-3:6.5,
          enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
          axis line style={latex-latex},
          ticklabel style={fill=white},
          ytick=\empty,
          xtick={-5,5}
]
\addplot[domain=5:26,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};
\addplot[domain=-6:5,dashed,thin,mark=none,samples=201] {sqrt(x + 5)};

\draw [densely dashed] (5,3.16227766) -- (5,0);
\draw [fill=white] (5,3.16227766) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}
\vskip0.25in

\noindent {\bfseries 2.)} Which of the following products is equal to an integral power of 10?
\[ \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\kern4em\alignShortstack{
 \LBL{1} &\ 1
&\LBL{2} &\ 5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)
&\LBL{3} &\ 5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{80}\right)
&\LBL{4} &\ 5^{-3}\left(\frac{1}{800}\right)
\\
 \LBL{5} &\ \left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^{3}15^{6}
&\LBL{6} &\ 2^{-6}25^{-3}
&\LBL{7} &\ \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{25}\right)^{3}
&\LBL{8} &\ \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^{6}\left(\frac{1}{5^{4}49}\right)^{3}
}}\]
\vskip0.25in
\end{document}
```